# ObjectDisposedException when trying to use the DBContext inside an IDistributedEventHandler

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, abp

I have an  ABP app where we are using the IDistributedEventHandle.  In these handlers I want to use the custom repository that we have in the application.  This repository inherits from the Volo EfCoreRepository.  However when the event handlers are executed I get ObjectDisposedException on the primary DbContext.  I'm assuming this is because its now being used outside of asp.net primary scope.

```
 public class EventHander : IDistributedEventHandler<ClientCreatedEto>,
    ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly ICustomRepository _repository;


    public EventHander (ICustomRepository repo)
    {
        _repository= repo;
    }

    public async Task HandleEventAsync(ClientCreatedEto eventData)
    {
       //error here
    }
}
```

I have also tried taking a dependency on IServiceProvider declaring a new scope and resolving the repository that way but I get the same exception.  How should the primary DBContext for the application be resolved in eventhandlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use **IUnitOfWorkManager** in the **HandleEventAsync** method to create a unit of work, and use repositoryin the unit of work.

```cs
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    // your _repository method code.
    await uow.CompleteAsync();
}
```

Or use [UnitOfWork] attribute.

```cs
[UnitOfWork]
public virtual async Task HandleEventAsync(ClientCreatedEto eventData)
{
   // your _repository method code.
}
```

Comment: thanks that works a treat. I will submit a PR for changes to docs to flag this.